# MySQL fill the memory and freezes

Tags: mysql, memory, innodb, freeze, fill

I have problem with my MySQL server (Debian/Lenny). Sometimes MySQL daemon fill memory and pages are not accesible. Restart of MySQL daemon helps, sometimes I have to restart whole server (can't connect with SSH anymore). Here is error log:

`InnoDB: Error: pthread_create returned 12<br/>
110228 23:58:36  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 43695

110228 23:58:36 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.

Version: '5.0.51a-24+lenny5'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Debian).`

---

### EDIT

Problem is, that I'm not using InnoDB engine. All my tables are in MyISAM engine. `SHOW ENGINES` says: No InnoDB. I did it before.

Here is my.cnf

> [client]
>   port = 3306
>   socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
>
> [mysqld_safe]
>   socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
>   nice = 0
>   log-error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
>
> [mysqld]
>   user = mysql
>   pid-file = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
>   socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
>   port = 3306
>   basedir = /usr
>   datadir = /var/lib/mysql
>   tmpdir = /tmp
>   language = /usr/share/mysql/english
>   skip-external-locking
>   log-error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
>   bind-address = 127.0.0.1
>   key_buffer = 16M
>   max_allowed_packet = 16M
>   thread_stack = 128K
>   thread_cache_size = 8
>   myisam-recover = BACKUP
>   query_cache_limit = 1M
>   query_cache_size = 16M
>   expire_logs_days = 10
>   max_binlog_size = 100M
>   skip-bdb
>
> [mysqldump]
>   quick
>   quote-names
>   max_allowed_packet = 16M
>
> [mysql]
>   [isamchk] key_buffer = 16M
>
> !includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/

And memory config? I'm not sure what you mean. Can you explain please? THANKS!!

Can anybody explain it to me? Thanks and sorry for my english.

Comment: You may want to turn off InnoDB as a workaround. It can be turned on even though all your tables are MyISAM. Run `SHOW ENGINES` to see if InnoDB is enabled.

Comment: Please paste your my.cnf and also your server config, memory etc.

Comment: You've likely got a config that eventually will use memory than you have available. Per above, please post your config - probably from /etc/my.cnf

Comment: I put my log. What you think?

Answer (score 0):

There's a mysql tuning primer script:

http://www.day32.com/MySQL/

Direct address of script to download: http://www.day32.com/MySQL/tuning-primer.sh

Run this script on your database server. It analizes how much memory is alloted for buffers and available memory and gives recommendations. Based on recommendations decrease sizes of mysql buffers.